# Hibernate - Value misleadingly being cast to integer

Tags: hibernate

I have an table with cars:

- CarId
- CustomerId
- ...

The mapping file looks like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.project.Car" table="tblCar">
        <id name="id" column="CarId" type="int">
            <generator class="native"/>  
        </id>
        <property column="CustomerId" name="customerId" type="text"/>
        <many-to-one column="CustomerId" name="customer" class="org.project.Customer" insert="false" update="false"  fetch="select"/>
        ...
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The problem lies in the many-to-one column: When I remove it, I can load all the cars. When it's there, I get the following error:

```
INFO: could not read column value from result set: Cus2_3_0_; Value 00005-C cannot be converted to INTEGER.
```

, whereas 00005-C is the Id of a customer.

Why on earth does Hibernate want to cast the customerId column to integer when it says text? Or can I only use integer IDs for foreign keys?

Edit:
My customer mapping roughly looks like this:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="org.project.Customer" table="tblCustomer">
        <id name="id" column="Id" type="integer">
            <generator class="native"/>  
        </id>
        <property column="CustomerId" name="customerId" type="text"/>
        ...
        <set name="cars" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select">
            <key column="CustomerId" not-null="true"/>
            <one-to-many class="org.project.Car"/>
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem:

I had to add property-ref to the key in my Customer mapping in order to tell Hibernate the key I am using is not the primary key but another field. That explain why Hibernate wanted to cast the values to int: The primary key is an integer.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what your "customer" mapping or table looks like I'm guessing that Hibernate is trying to use the "CustomerId" column of your customer table by default.

You need to specify the KEY column on your customer table in your mapping.

Comment: I added the mapping of my customer table.